# How to solve this error like Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] Unsupported options `{:exclusive=>true}` for target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I clone the project fro from repository and this project podfile containing the version `0.39.0`.When i tried `pod install` command then i always get the error like 
`Podfile` file: [!] Unsupported options `{:exclusive=>true} for target’`. Podfile looks like the following

```
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods

    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

end

target ‘product_DEV' do
    shared_pods
end

target ‘productTests', :exclusive => true do

    shared_pods

end
```

How to solve this issue? Please help me.

Comment: please show your podfile, so we can get the clear idea.

Answer (score 1):

- `:exclusive => true do` has been deprecated check out [this](http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-1.0-Migration-Guide/) migration guide.

  - try re-initing the pod file,so that you can have latest pod file.
  - Or try changing the pod file content to something like this,

    ```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
    # platform :ios, '9.0'

    target 'product_DEV' do

    use_frameworks!

    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    target 'productTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    end

    end
    ```
  - This is a bind shot, give it a try it may help,Check other reference [ref1](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4853),[ref2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4706)
  - Check [ref2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4706) `abstract_target` may help.

    abstract_target 'DummyTarget' do
    pod "..."
    target 'App1' do
    end
    target 'App2' do
    end
    end

Comment: but my pod version shows like 0.39.0.I s it possible to solve issue without remove ':exclusive => true do' this ?

Comment: if cloned repo is public one can you share the clone url,Check [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6163),If u r using **xcode 8** then it works with **CocoaPods 1.1.0** only.

Comment: I want use xcode7.2.I cant share clone url.Its private

Comment: I had tried downgrading my cocopods version to support `podfile(versio 0.39.0)`,but ended up with error `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem '0.39.0' (>= 0) in any repository`. I think we can't use older versions. Better you try to downgrade ur cocopods version. This is what i used to downgrade `sudo gem install cocoapods ver 0.39.0 -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`